# gdal_polygonize ignores some polygons

Tags: gdal, polygon, polygonize

I want to polygonize [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pwst.png) PNG. I try

> gdal_polygonize pic.png -f "GeoJSON" polygonized.geojson

but I get only 11 polygons instead of more than 20. What is the cause or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html that gdal_polygonize is using only one band of the source image. Better wording would be:

> creates vector polygons for all connected regions of pixels in the
>   raster sharing a common pixel value **on the selected band**

From the script itself you can see that by default band 1 is selected

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_polygonize.py

You are getting different results by selecting other bands as

```
gdal_polygonize -f "ESRI Shapefile" -b 2 BX1CLUO.png poly2.shp
gdal_polygonize -f "ESRI Shapefile" -b 3 BX1CLUO.png poly3.shp
```

Band 2 yields 40 polygons for me and band 3 55 polygons. Low number of polygons from band 1 comes from your palette, for example both white and yellow has 255 as the value of red band.

You will notice that the script if turning the polygons around. Create a fake BX1CLUO.pgw file for preventing that:

```
1
0
0
-1
1000
1000
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yeah the script turned the polygons around but I fix that by changing the y-coordinates later. So how do I know how many bands my png has and do I have to select them all? Will there be the same polygon in more than one band?

Comment: Use gdalinfo. You will find that there is an alpha band as well and you may want to test also if the -nomask option has some effect. But perhaps you should convert your RGB(A) image into paletted 1-band image with http://gdal.org/rgb2pct.html.

Comment: Trying that, I get 28996 features in the shapefile. Some parts of the image have a kind of rastered colour. You have to eliminate that manually.

Comment: -nomask has no effect. I had also 28996 polygons but than I used rgb2pct -n 5 ... and it worked(around 70 polygons). But now I lose the colour information. Instead of DN:255 i get DN:0 etc. How can I obtain the original colour or better the RGB value?

Comment: Perhaps you need to make three vector layers and do some magic with spatial operations and joins. The result should be minimum number of polygons with three attributes for RGB. I believe it can be done with QGIS or OpenJUMP.

Comment: I made a workaround with rgb2pct and gdalinfo. Thanks.